# Accessing service from exported function in a module declaration in Angular 2+

Tags: angular, typescript, service, injectable

I have the following Module declaration:

```
import { ConnectionService } from './services/connection.service';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Http, RequestOptions } from '@angular/http';
import { AuthHttp, AuthConfig } from 'angular2-jwt';

export function authHttpServiceFactory(http: Http, options: RequestOptions) {
  return new AuthHttp(new AuthConfig({
    tokenName: 'token',
    tokenGetter: (() => sessionStorage.getItem('token'))
  }), http, options);
}

@NgModule({
  providers: [
    {
      provide: AuthHttp,
      useFactory: authHttpServiceFactory,
      deps: [Http, RequestOptions]
    }
  ],
})

export class AuthModule { }
```

and Service:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable()
export class ConnectionService {
    id;

    getToken() {
        return JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem('token'))[this.id];
    }
}
```

I need to use the Services method "getToken" in the tokenGetter on the Modules exported function, but I can't make it work and Google hasn't answered my question (or I haven't been able to look properly).

Answer (score 1):

Hi can you try like this

```
export function authHttpServiceFactory(http: Http, options: RequestOptions) {
  return new AuthHttp(new AuthConfig({
       tokenName: 'token',
       tokenGetter: (() => new ConnectionService().getToken())
       }), http, options);
 }
```

Comment: Thank you but it didn't work for me. In the end I made it the other way around and defined the "AuthHttp" object directly inside the service.

Comment: I couldn't try it. On the real project I have a constructor in the service to access Http and other stuff, so it didn't let me. But in any case I think adding the object to the service instead of the other way around is a better approach, at least in my case.